# PaperJs Adjusting width and height after rotation

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas, paperjs

I have an item that is rotated and I want to change the width and height base on no rotation.

When I rotate the item the width and height totally change and the re-size direction remain north and south.
[image: a busy cat]

How do it make sure the width is updated base on the new rotation
[image: a busy cat]

Is their a setting I need change or anyone know a math formula I can use to calculate the new size base on the rotation.

Thank you any help or reference is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The path.bounds property will contain the bounds of the object even when rotated. This makes it straight forward to implement what you have drawn. See the example I made below.

```js
// Create an empty project and a view for the canvas:
paper.setup(document.getElementById('myCanvas'));
// Make the paper scope global, by injecting it into window:
paper.install(window);

// Create the original rectagle
var point = new Point(20, 20);
var size = new Size(60, 60);
var rect = new Path.Rectangle(point, size);
rect.fillColor = new paper.Color(1, 0, 0)
rect.rotation = 15;

// Create the bounds rectangle
var boundsPath = new Path.Rectangle(rect.bounds);
boundsPath.strokeColor = new Color(0, 0, 0);


// Make a nice little animation:
function onFrame(event) {
  // Every frame, rotate the path by 2 degrees 
  rect.rotate(2);

  // Recreate the bounds rectangle
  boundsPath.remove();
  boundsPath = new Path.Rectangle(rect.bounds);
  boundsPath.strokeColor = new Color(0, 0, 0);
}

view.draw();
view.onFrame = onFrame;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.9.22/paper-full.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```